# Using Visio to generate MySQL DDL

Tags: mysql, visio, ddl

I have a database model diagram created in MS Visio which I would like to export to DDL file to create a MySQL database. I've already installed the MySQL ODBC driver, which I can successfully use to generate DDL file, but I have some problems anyway.

Visio puts quotation marks around the table names which are also reserved words (like user). This is not OK, since MySQL uses backticks (`) and not quotation marks (") for this purpose.

MySQL ODBC driver also changes the BLOB data type to LONGVARBINARY, so it cannot be used directly with MySQL when creating the database.

Does anyone have any suggestion how to deal with these two problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than editing it? No.

You might consider using [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/). It is very similar to visio if you create everything in design mode. Additionally, with the paid version you can generate a pdf document as well for distribution (or plop that PDF into the flow chart diagrams, etc in visio) or you could possibly create a plugin that would generate a valid visio file on output since workbench is fully extensible via plugins.

Comment: That's what I did in the end.

Comment: I find that software very buggy.

Comment: @slotishtype, In the early days I would have said the same. However, I will say that they seem very responsive to bug reports. I filed a few back in the day and they were resolved pretty quickly. I'd advise you to report your errors! http://wb.mysql.com/?page_id=53

Comment: Fair enough.  I used visio to reverse-engineer a database yesterday and it worked a treat.  I was labouring with the workbench before hand.  Good it works better now.

Comment: @slotishtype, yeah I like Visio 2010 tbh because I can focus on modeling for anything, not just mysql. I use MySQL Workbench when I'm in a mysql shop that can't afford to give me the tools I prefer :P