# Visio 2003 ERM to SQL Server script

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-modeling, visio

my question is simple:

Is there anyway to generate the database sql creaton script from a Visio 2003 model?

I prefer Visio, however can be other program (freeware) that allows me to somehow agilize the process between the model and the sql code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I think the commands to generate DDL disappeared with Visio 2003.  Apparently you now need the "Enterprise Edition" or some such dreck.

Also, this is a repeat of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752434/using-visio-to-generate-mysql-ddl) , and the original pointed to this free service: http://aboutwhatever.net/posts/visio-2007-database-model-ddl-generation
which does allow you to do what you want, with certain restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time, there was [Visio for Enterprise Architects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visio).

There is [a promising add-in for Visio 2010](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alberto_ferrari/archive/2010/04/16/visio-forward-engineer-addin-for-office-2010.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage).